# Django + Apache + mod_wsgi: Import Error

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi, importerror

I have seen others post on this on StackOverflow (mainly for Django 1.4), but none of those provided a successful solution for me. I receive the following error:

`ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named myproject.settings`

Windows 8, Apache-2.2, Django-1.5.4, Python-2.7

Directory tree:

```
+-- C:\
|   +-- Apache22
|       +-- conf
|           +-- httpd.conf
|       +-- logs
|           +-- error.log
|
|   +-- Python27
|       +-- Scripts
|           +-- myapp
|           +-- myproject
|               +-- apache
|                   +-- mod.wsgi
|               +-- myproject
|                   +-- settings.py
|           +-- django_admin.py
```

httpd.conf:

```
...............
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias / c:/python27/scripts/myproject/apache/mod.wsgi
<Directory "c:/python27/scripts/myproject/apache">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

mod.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

error.log:

```
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=6072): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Python27/Scripts/myproject/apache/mod.wsgi'.
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self.load_middleware()
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._setup(name)
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named myproject.settings
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=6072): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Python27/Scripts/myproject/apache/mod.wsgi'.
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self.load_middleware()
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._setup(name)
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Sun Sep 22 21:56:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named myproject.settings
```

Output of my sys path:

```
>>>import sys
>>> for path in sys.path: print path
...

C:\Windows\SYSTEN32\python27.zip
C:\Python27\DLLs
C:\Python27\lib
C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
```

settings.py:

```
# Django settings for myproject project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '9zb*5mqfgy!(17p^$-fh7n@33i=n%5k7!j#)+!vd$3j(7y2@zh'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: So where is settings.py? You don't show it in that directory structure.

Comment: i dont think we need it for this error

Comment: The error is `Could not import settings` and you think we don't need the settings file location?

Comment: Use gunicorn, it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I find it odd that your app is out of your project, as well as your `django.py`.
Your tree should look like this:

```
── myproject/
 │   ├── django.wsgi
 │   ├── manage.py
 │   ├── myproject/
 │   │   ├── __init__.py
 │   │   ├── settings.py
 │   │   ├── urls.py 
 │   │   └── wsgi.py
 │   ├── myapp/
 │   │   ├── models.py
 ....
```

So yes i gess it is a path issue.

Try this for `mod.wsgi`:

```
import os
import sys

path = 'C:/your/path/myproject'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: Two years ago I forgot about `__init__.py` in each package :)

Answer (score 2):

You have not told mod_wsgi where your package is by updating sys.path. See the WSGIPythonPath setting in the mod_wsgi documentation on the Django site.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#basic-configuration